# Why does the image not loading?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I have been facing this situation where the HTML code copied from affiliate network does not load image. I have tried the value of the source attribute in a new browser window, it gets load in this case. But when I try to use the HTML code, it does not load the image.

```
<a href="https://imp.i115008.net/c/2911356/788193/11298" target="_top" id="788193">
  <img src="//a.impactradius-go.com/display-ad/11298-788193" border="0" alt="" width="180" height="150"/>
</a>
<img height="0" width="0" src="https://imp.pxf.io/i/2911356/788193/11298" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;" border="0" />
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the HTML. What does your developer console and network tab say?

Comment: oh I got it from the network tab, my ad blocker extension blocked the image from being load.

Comment: I feel there's some irony here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem, image does load properly, second source is just dot. Check out following for same example in action.

https://jsfiddle.net/k2qduspf/1/

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://imp.i115008.net/c/2911356/788193/11298" target="_top" id="788193"><img src="//a.impactradius-go.com/display-ad/11298-788193" border="0" alt="" width="180" height="150"/></a><img height="0" width="0" src="https://imp.pxf.io/i/2911356/788193/11298" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;" border="0" />
</body>
</html>
```